# AutoComplete does not save when there's a postback before Submit

Tags: autocomplete, textbox, postback, submit

I have a very simple asp.net form.

a text box,
a dropdownlist with autopostback,
a submit button

1. now if i type in some value into the textbox
2. and then select an item in the dropdown which causes a page postback.
3. then click on submit button

the value in the text box does not get saved into the autocomplete data store.

if i do the opposite.

1. select an item from the dropdown which will cause a page postback.
2. type in some values in the textbox.
3. click submit.
   the value is saved for the autocomplete.

I think this may have something to do with the page life cycle and the viewstate. but how do i get around this issue? I'm using IE8.

I have tried the AutoCompleteSaveForm command. but it does not work if there's a postback immediately after the execution of it.

Comment: why do you need the drop down to post back when an item is selected?, or can you handle this on the submit button?

Comment: the actual form is more complicated. this is just a simplified example. the dropdown is linked to another dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Use this for IE:

```
if($.browser.msie){window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm(FormName)};
```

It does not work for Firefox and I'm trying to find the answer for that....

Comment: you have to call this, before you submit; so it would look like this if($.browser.msie){window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm(FormBusSearch)}; with Jquery you would then add your submit .. $('#FormBusSearch').submit();